# i cannot install mysql plugin keyring_file.dll

Tags: mysql, innodb, wamp

I have been trying to install the `keyring_file.dll` of MySQL 5.7.26 plugin from WAMP 3.1.9 without success. It keeps me telling in the CMD Prompt:

> ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'keyring_file'; Plugin initialization function failed.

...and the MySQL log states:

> [ERROR] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'File 'C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/keyring\keyring' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)'

Could somebody help me figure out what the root cause is?

Comment: Is this an upgrade?  If so, did you run mysql_upgrade?

Comment: Check the path to keyring in your my.cnf file

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that error is that mysql can't locate the keyring_file.dll file.

To fix that do the ff:

1. Edit the `my.ini` file located in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\` and add the ff in the `[mysqld]` block:

   ```
   early-plugin-load=keyring_file.dll
   keyring_file_data=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/lib/plugin/keyring_file
   ```

   [image: It should be like this]
2. Restart the MySQL service:

   ```
   net stop MySQL57
   net start MySQL57
   ```
3. Validate that the keyring plugin is now active:

   ```
   SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';
   ```